# How to send email to user only five time in a month

Tags: php, wordpress

I am working on a contact form. i need to send email to users according to number of times they have set in a month. for ex. if a user set 5 for contact request then he will get email from 5 users in a month. Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

This is the first idea that comes to mind. Store their settings in a MySQL table and have a separate column for how many times they have already been emailed this month. You can have a daily cron job that does something similar to this:

```
$select_result = mysqli_query($database_connection, "SELECT email_pref,
email_this_month, user_id FROM users WHERE email_this_month > 0");
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($select_result, MYSQLI_NUM)) {
 if ($row[1] =< $row[0]) {
   ///send email
   //Code to update the MySQL server, something like "UPDATE users SET email_this_month = email_this_month - 1 WHERE user_id = $row[3]";
  }
}
```

You should also have stored a date in your DB that keeps track of their "months" and you can preform a date interval command through SQL or PHP to figure out if a month has elasped since they signed up, and if so, reset the number of times they have been emailed and set that date equal to the current date to reference it again in the future. DATE_ADD through SQL or date functions on strings in PHP would work

http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-add.php
http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_date_add.asp

Or alternatively, there are some SESSION variables you can store or COOKIES in the server for every user, but I'm not sure how efficient that is. I think this is probably quicker

Comment: I need to send email when any guest user fill the contact form to registered users.Do i need to save month also when a user register and need to match the month with current month when any guest user will fill the contact foem. Do i need to set a cron job for this?

Answer (score 1):

How often are you sending emails?
If you made important emails once a week that could be a solution as well.

You might consider creating different email lists. 
Weekly / Daily / Twice Monthly.

Comment: i need to send email only when any guest user will fill the contact form.

Comment: So it's not a subscription email, like a newsletter?
More like a follow up email, or a sales email?

Answer (score 0):

Create a file that will run automatically from time to time that will store how many times the user wants to get emails a month and how many times he received in the current month.
The file will then run through each user in the database. It will check how many times user got email compared to how many times he wants. If user needs to be getting another email then it will send him and it will update the database values.